# Javascript Reference Outer Shadow Variables from Inner Object

Tags: javascript

Quick question - It is possible to reference a shadow variable from a IIFE? I would like to reference to the a in global, is that possible?

```
var a = 2;

(function foo(){

    var a = 3;
    console.log( a ); // 3
    console.log( this.a ); // I want to reference to the var a = 2 in global
})();

console.log( a ); // 2
```

Comment: `this.a` is already referenced to `2`. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, (though not the best thing to do). You could reference the **window** object:

```
window.a = 2;

(function foo(){
    var a = 3;
    console.log(window.a);  // 2
...
```